# Sessions in Sinatra using Facebook authentication

Tags: ruby, facebook, session, sinatra

I'm very new to ruby & Sinatra and I have a basic question:

The app I'm trying to build will use Facebook as it's sole method of authenticating users into the app. I want to store a local users table which will contain only the facebook uid along with some user preferences. I have looked at a couple of gems which allow me to authenticate against the facebook API, however I am unsure how to control sessions within my application once I have established the user is valid. I have been using the [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem for talking to facebook, and I have also seen the [sinatra-session](http://mjijackson.com/sinatra-session) gem for running the session side of things.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can manage my sessions once a user has logged in using their facebook account?

Comment: What do you mean by "control the sessions" / "manage the sessions"? Are you asking how to store data associated with the session? Are you asking how to figure out who the current user is?

Comment: More figure out who the current user is and control access to 'member-only' areas of the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote an example sinatra app with this functionality and used the built-in sessions from sinatra. look here, maybe this helps you: https://github.com/benben/simple-ruby-facebook-example

Comment: Thanks Ben, that's very similar to the approach I have gone for in the end using Koala - Bookmarked!