# Showing users unique info when facebook authenticate , with Sinatra/ Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, omniauth, datamapper

Super beginner here.

Here's what I am trying to do: 
Build a basic to do list app, where User X logs in with facebook, adds some items, sees them, logs out. User Y/Z/M/etc, should be able to log in see their OWN list, add their OWN items, etc.
 **AKA: a standard web app where you log in to your account and see your own info.**

What I have so far: 
Ability to build a list, log in with Facebook and having it know your name. 
**However, the list stays the same whether I log in or whether my friend logs in with her account.**

What I need to do, and don't know how:
**I need each user to be able to create and see their own list, and be able to come back to it and still see it/ add to it, etc.**

I don't even know how this is called, would this be a database of users each with their own set of data? Would the lists need to be set up so they could be stored as a chunk of data?
Does it have something to do with this :[Sessions in Sinatra using Facebook authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453797/sessions-in-sinatra-using-facebook-authentication) If so, what?

If anyone could be give me some really really basic directions as to where to go from here, any tutorials or what I should be googling for, that'd be awesome.

Here's my main piece of code (warning: it's really messy) :

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'time'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'omniauth'
require 'omniauth-facebook'
#TODO require 'omniauth-att'

SCOPE = 'email,read_stream'

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/queue.db")


class SinatraApp < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :sessions, true
    set :inline_templates, true
    set :protection, :except => :frame_options
end

class Note  
  include DataMapper::Resource  
  property :id, Serial  
  property :content, Text, :required => true  
  property :complete, Boolean, :required => true, :default => false  
  property :created_at, DateTime  
  property :updated_at, DateTime  
end 

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,         Serial
  property :uid,        String
  property :name,       String
  property :created_at, DateTime
end



###### no clue what this does ##############
DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

enable :session


use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, '464630283595639','5e4c7ad43bf111c10287c981d51127a3',:scope => SCOPE, :display => "popup"
    #provider :att, 'client_id', 'client_secret', :callback_url => (ENV['BASE_DOMAIN']
  end




###### root ##############

get '/' do
  if current_user
    @notes = Note.all :order => :id.desc  
    @title = 'Movie Queue'
    erb :home
  else
    ' <a href="/sign_in">sign in with Facebook</a>'
  end
end


###### authentication ##############

["/sign_in/?", "/signup/?"].each do |path|
  get path do
    redirect '/auth/facebook'
  end
end

get '/auth/:name/callback' do
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.first_or_create({ :uid => auth["uid"]}, {
    :uid => auth["uid"],
    :name => auth["first_name"],
    :created_at => Time.now })
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect '/'
end


helpers do
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.get(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end



##list making part###
post '/' do  
  n = Note.new  
  n.content = params[:content]  
  n.save  
  redirect '/'  
end


get '/:id/delete' do
  n = Note.get params[:id]
  if n.destroy
    redirect '/', :notice => 'Note deleted successfully.'
  else
    redirect '/', :error => 'Error deleting note.'
  end
end

get '/:id/complete' do  
  n = Note.get params[:id]  
  n.complete = n.complete ? 0 : 1 # flip it  
  n.save  
  redirect '/'  
end


########## logout and error handlers #############

  get '/logout' do
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect '/'
  end

  get '/auth/failure' do
    erb "<h1>Authentication Failed:</h1><h3>message:<h3> <pre>#{params}</pre>"
  end

  get '/auth/:provider/deauthorized' do
    erb "#{params[:provider]} has deauthorized this app."
  end

  get '/protected' do
    throw(:halt, [401, "Not authorized\n"]) unless session[:authenticated]
    erb "<pre>#{request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_json}</pre><hr>
         <a href='/logout'>Logout</a>"
  end


end


########## don't know what this is #############


SinatraApp.run! if __FILE__ == $0
```

Comment: By the way, I think what you've achieved so far is very impressive for someone who claims to be a super beginner (I know that sounds patronising, sorry! but kudos to you)

Comment: I think she cheated a little bit and employed some sneaky code copy pasting here (comments "no clue what this is"), but none the less it's pretty good :) Btw. Helena `DataMapper.finalize/auto_upgrade` you can find those explained in [the docs](http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html). Just search for those terms on that page. They are explained on that page.

Comment: I'll definitely look that up. Been doing it a little rushed, but should take a step back and look some things up :) Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know Datamapper, but this should get you going.

---

There needs to be a way to associate a note with a user. <strike>This needs a table in the database, some would call it `users_notes`, personally I prefer `users_rel_notes`, (perhaps Datamapper has a convention for this… YMMV). Anyway, the table will have a minimum of 2 columns - the user's id, and the note id.</strike> You don't need a separate table as I wrote before (I'm lacking a bit of sleep, sorry!), that would be for a many to many relationship where a user could have several notes and a note could be associated with several users. For what you have, where only the owner of a note has access to it, it requires a one to many relationship. You could add a column to the `notes` table to store the user id.

Then, in the User class, add an [association](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html) to the Note class, it's a one to many association and in Datamapper that's a `has n`, e.g.

```
has n, :notes
```

Now when you have a user instance, you can (probably) call the notes for that user via:

```
user.notes
```

I see you have the helper `current_user` defined, so if someone is logged on you could call `current_user.notes` to get back all the notes for the logged in user.

Remember, when you add a note to make sure you add a record to the association table, (probably, read the link) via `user.notes << my_new_note`.

The session is the information you keep around to identify the user and any other little bits of info that you may recurrently need. The likelyhood is, you're just storing an id for the user, or the facebook token that identifies them, and then during a request, if it's needed then you'll look inside the cookie, grab the id, look up that user by the id and get a user instance. Session info can be stored in several ways, most often cookies but you can use anything you would use to store any other data.

Comment: I think there should be a reverse association that would be present in the `Notes` class: `belongs_to :user` isn't it?

Comment: @Kashyap only if you find you need to call `note.user` at some point. I tend to only write an association if it's needed by the code.